# How can we avoid mistake in LL(1) parse tree?

Tags: context-free, compilers, parsers

I'm learning about *LL(1) parse tree*. We need to find `first` and `follow` in order to construct a *LL(1) parse tree*. Each and every time when I find `first` and `follow` I'm missing one or the other terminal as we to `back track` each production. When makes me end up in wrong *LL(1) parse tree*. Is there any standardized way to check the `first and follow` table ?